# How to make a multi-video driver Linux system?

Tags: xorg, drivers, video

I'm trying to create a USB that I can carry anywhere with my system on it, I know there are Live distros that can be used that way, but I need a very specific installation. The problem is that the USB will be used in a wide variety of machines with different hardware and sometimes the video only has a couple of resolutions available while booting with a live CD in that same machine provides more resolutions.

How do distros detect video card, load modules and configure X so that they can run in almost any computer (video wise)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen in the [Debian doc](https://wiki.debian.org/Xorg) that if xorg.conf is missing (which is my case) Xorg will probe your hardware on every startup. So I did an `apt-get install firmware-linux-nonfree` (I have Debian stable) and installed the xserver-xorg-video-????? (most popular video cards).

After having tested in some machines now, this seem to be the answer since all the tests have been successfull.